# Retrieve information about Single Windows of an Running Application in NSRunningApplication

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, window, nsrunningapplication

Im writing an iPad app that should be able to manipuliate single windows of an mac applications eg. close them, minimize them, et cetera. I got all the network stuff working but im having trouble with retrieving information from my mac.

I can get Application information with the NSWorkspace and NSRunningApplication classes. But how do i get specific information about the open windows an Application has. How can i find out how many windows for example my finder or firefox has open and how can i manipulate them separately. 
I havent found a way to get information about specific windows from an application in the API.

I would be very thankful if anybody had some suggestions on how to get that information. 
Thanks in advance, Damir